# GrapeCity ActiveReportsJS How to pass Authorization Header for DataSource

Tags: javascript, vue.js, activereports

I'm asking on behalf of our UI dev.  He's coding in VueJS, but this should be specific to the ActiveReportsJS report viewer or report designer only since it's still just JavaScript.

We're using JWT's with our .net core web API, so we need to pass an Authorization header with each report datasource request.  There seems to be no documentation at all on this, and I would believe that most companies would require some type of authorization to access reports so that the endpoints aren't just sitting out there for anyone to consume freely.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance for any info.

Answer (score 1):

The official answer from GrapeCity is that they don't support authorization for datasources in the JS version.  I'm not sure what the use for this product is, but it definitely doesn't fit our use-case.